# Using a record separator of different length

Tags: perl

I understand that the following script would print out line(s) separated by '--' (2 dashes), but how can I use it when there are many '-' (dashes)?

```
{
   local $/ = "--\n";
   while (<>) {
      chomp;
      print;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own data stream parser. `$/` [isn't up to the task:](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR)

> Remember: the value of $/ is a string, not a regex. awk has to be better for something. :-)

---

But a line that ends with three dashes and a newline is also a line that ends with two dashes and a newline. Wouldn't it be sufficient just to swap out the `chomp` command?

```
{
   local $/ = "--\n";
   while (<>) {
      chomp; s/\-+$//;    # chop off minimum record separator AND extra dashes
      print;
   }
}
```

or

```
       chomp && s/\-+$//
```

for the case where the last record in the data doesn't end with the record separator string.

Comment: No self-rolling needed, we already have [`Data::Record`](http://p3rl.org/Data::Record).